# Train and test in TensorFlow with CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tensorflow

I have a train.csv and a test.csv. I want to use tensorflow to look at the training.csv and print out a two column CSV file for the test.csv file. The first column being the id and the second column being what the tensorflow predicts is the category for the id. I am using python.

Comment: And what is your question?  (Hint: the answer to the implicit 'would someone write this for me?' is usually no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever Tensorflow predicts, once you do .eval() on that, it becomes a 'standard' Python datatype, which you can write to CSV using usual non-Tensorflow APIs.

Here's a snippet of code that does just that (pieced it together from various parts of a larger file, so excuse if not fully coherent)

```
lVerb = open('your_file.csv', 'w')
lVerb.write('Predcited,Actual\n')

guessY = tf.argmax(Y, 1).eval({X: feature_batch, keep_prob: 1})
trueY = tf.argmax(label_batch, 1).eval()

for j in range(0, batch_size):
    curGuess = guessY[j]
    curTrue = trueY[j]
    lVerb.write('{},{}\n'.format(curGuess, curTrue))

lVerb.close()
```

As you can see above, the output of TF's .eval() operation or of Session.run() is a standard Python datatype, such as numpy array/etc., depending on what you are doing. In the above case, you are writing them to CSV independently of Tensorflow